# How many different partial and total orderings can we define on the set A?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many different partial orderings can we define on the set A = {1, 2}?

And

How many different total orderings can we define on the set A = {1, 2}?

To be honest I don't really understand those questions, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what a partial order is? A total order?

Comment: An ordering of a set $A$ is a relation on $A$, so in particular it is a subset of $A\times A$. Can you write out the power set of $A\times A$ and pick out which elements thereof are partial/total orderings? This is not an approach you'd want to use in general, but for a two-element set it should give you a good sense of things.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott. I understand what is the partial ordering is when the relation is defined. But here we can define infinite amount of relations.

Comment: You don’t have to. Every relation on $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$, and $A\times A$ has $2^2=4$ elements, so it has only $2^4=16$ subsets. Moreover, only a few of these subsets are partial orders. In a pinch you could write down every relation on $A$, but you know that a partial order is reflexive, which cuts down the number quite a bit. Try listing all of the reflexive relations on $A$, for starters; there are only a handful.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott. So the reflexive relations are {(1, 1), (2, 2)},  {(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)},  {(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)} and {(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)}. By antisymmetric property we are throwing last one away, and transitive leaves the remaining three untouched. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly right. Now how many of those three are total?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott. Numbers 1 and 2 are comparable, so I assume, that the answer is the same.

Comment: No, one of them is not total, because in it $1$ and $2$ are **not** comparable; can you pick it out?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott. Ok. Now I got it. {(1, 1), (2, 2)} is not totally ordered, because (1, 2) or (2, 1) is missing. right?

Comment: That’s right. I’ve posted an answer showing the Hasse diagrams of these three partial orders to make things as clear as possible.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott. Thank you, sir!!!

Comment: You’re very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you’ve found the orders, here are their Hasse diagrams:

```
          1   2                 2                 1  
                                |                 |  
                                1                 2
```

The first relation is the equivalence relation of equality on the set $A=\{1,2\}$; the other two are the two possible total orders.